# Is JWT more secure in a Reactjs SSR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, jwt, microservices

After hours reading about JWT I am more confused than before starting. Why are jwt being so used if they are not secure within a stateless application? I understand that if a hacker stoles the JWT from a valid user, then that's it, game over.
I am currently starting building an e-commerce with reactjs , and I am struggling with many things. What I want to achieve is two have multiple apis (asp.net web api projects) working (ProductsApi,PaymentsApi, etc..), kind of a reduced version of microservices (without struggling with the communication, api gateway and others things from the beginning ). So, in order to accomplish this I need that a user after putting its username and password, be authorized to use the correct apis. So far I am able to generate jwt that can be validated by all the api projects (https://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/). So, what I understand is that I have two options:

1. Stateless application: Get the jwt from the authentication server and save on localstorage, so it can be used when accessing the apis. (insecure as hell)
2. Reactjs inside a Asp.net MVC(Server side rendering): Use cookies (httpcookieonly) to access the apis.

The way I see it, the best approach is #2, so I was planning to still use the jwt thing, BUT adding a claim to it with the sessionid generated by asp.net MVC. Would that make the jwt "secure"? Can it still be stolen and used from another person?

I know I am talking about many things at the same time. It's just I am so confused right now, and I dont find any good post on internet that can suit my needs.

Comment: Your premise seems to be somewhat incorrect. JWTs have an valid from and expiration date (`nbf` and `exp` in the payload) which you should set when you issue it and verify for every request. You can't forge because usually JWTs are signed (the `alg` field in the header and the signature after the payload). Thus the common approach is that you make the token only valid for eg. 30min. Even if it gets stolen the attacker can use it only for 30min max. For your regular users this means they need to get a new JWT every 30min.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For me that is a huge problem. I mean, if somebody was able to stole the jwt once, it means he/she can do it again and again, which very dangerous, because I am planning to work with credit card information. What do you think about using the sessionid (reactjs inside a mvc application) as an extra claim?